# Perdi Conexion MV desdpues de restablecer Firewall de windows

Tags: windows, firewall

hola buenas tardes quisiera ver si alguien me ayuda pues he perdido conexion con mi instancia por Escritorio remoto despues de restablecer el firewall, ya no me puedo conectar, lo mismo me paso cuando le instale un antivirus. que fue kaspersky y tuve que hacer la instancia de nuevo favor si me pudiecen ayudar a poder retomar el control de la maquina sin la necesidad de eliminarla y crearla de nuevo se los agradeceria muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

hola buenas tardes quisiera ver si alguien me ayuda pues he perdido conexion con mi instancia por Escritorio remoto despues de restablecer el firewall, ya no me puedo conectar, lo mismo me paso cuando le instale un antivirus. que fue kaspersky y tuve que hacer la instancia de nuevo favor si me pudiecen ayudar a poder retomar el control de la maquina sin la necesidad de eliminarla y crearla de nuevo se los agradeceria muchas gracias.